# How do I use MySQLs Point type from Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have written a Python game that uses positions on a grid.
I want to store these positions in MySQL.

I have a MySQL database table that uses a POINT type.

I have imported the mysql.connector library.

I believe I should write this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO player_position(coordinate) VALUES (%s)"
values = (GeomFromText('Point(39 55)')

cursor.execute(query, values)
db.commit()
```

I get this error:
name 'GeomFromText' is not defined

Is this the correct way of doing this?

If it is, where is GeomFromText defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think that GeomFromText is unsupported and not well documented. Instead, you could try as follows:

```
query = "INSERT INTO player_position(coordinate) VALUES Point(39, 55);"

cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

or

```
query = """INSERT INTO player_position(coordinate) VALUES (PointFromWKB(point(%s, %s)))"""
cursor.execute(query, (39, 55))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  I get the error:  
  Message=1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)'

I also tried it with the ; removed from line 1

Comment: I think that I should have written `Point(x, y)` instead of `Point(x y)` as corrected now.
What happen if you run just a string query in your mysql without using Python? For instance,
`query = "INSERT INTO player_position(coordinate) VALUES (Point(39, 55))"`

Comment: I tried this in my test table

query = "INSERT INTO test(coordinate) VALUES (Point(12, 12))"

That works in Python and MySQL query .  

Trying to use values=  is what is/was blowing me up.  I'm assuming that a problem of the Python mysql.connector library

Comment: I think that you need to provide a tuple for the second argument of execute() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 39
y = 55
coordinates = f"Point({x} {y})"
query = "INSERT INTO player_position(coordinates) " \
        "VALUES ST_PointFromText(%(coordinates)s)"
cursor.execute(query, {"coordinates": coordinates})
db.commit()
```

Using an [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) to format the coordinates to the "Point(x y)" format. [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) can also be used instead.

Then [ST_PointFromText](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_pointfromtext/) to parse it in MySQL.